# how to find duplicate words in an excel column using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file and I need to extract all the common words in the strings that I have in my column.

Comment: Why are you limited to Python? 
Excel uses VBA, it would be easier to do it in VBA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lots of q&a finding words in strings on here, should have a look.

Comment: @KaviHarjani do you have any idea how I can do it with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned the python library you are using, I assume you are using PANDAS library.

```
                import pandas as pd
                data = pd.read_excel('C:\Temp\data.xlsx')
                print(data)

                boolean = df['Student'].duplicated().any() # True
```

Comment: in my case I don't have a specific words to find its duplicates, I have to figure out all the common words or the words that are duplicated without knowing them in advance.